# Difficulties Miracast iPhone -> Raspberry Pi -> HDMI -> TV

Tags: pi-2, kodi, shairplay, chromecast

What I want to do?

1. Cast using the miracast icon from my iPhone to RPI which is connected with HDMI to TV.

OR

2. Mirror Screen to do the same thing.

---

Problems I have encountered:

- RaspberryCast 3.0 (Using browser, url casting): works, but I can't do much with it since I'm trying to cast video's from an app out of the app store to the tv. There are no URL's of the video's provided.
- Kodi: doesn't let me cast video, only audio using airplay.
- AirPlay Receiver (shairport): doesn't let me cast video, only audio
- LazyCast (was my best bet): I can't seem to find the device when terminal showing me a PIN. I can't figure out where to fill in the pin on the source device as when I press the miracast button, it doesn't find the RPI.

---

So basically, I'm trying to do the same trick as a chromecast but using an iPhone. I understand that android users have it much more simple.
Is it just impossible what I'm trying? Or am I doing things wrong?

Answer (score 1):

See if you can build [MiracleCast](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast) on your RPi. It should work as a Miracast protocol receiver aka [sink](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast#steps-to-use-it-as-sink).

There's also [aethercast](https://git.launchpad.net/aethercast) package in Ununtu Launchpad, but I suppose it will require more effort to port it on Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no out-of-the-box solution. Some individuals posted videos on YouTube showing video-playback from an [iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwtbKHGZa_M)/[macOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsELdYbwyRI) device named rPlay. But so far I know noone who had his hands on such a thing. Also the vidoes are quite old.

If you are willing to spend months to figure out a way then go for it. Alternatively I suggest you spend some money on a device like [EZcast](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07F63PKK2). I own it myself and is reliable. Works with iOS, macOS and Windows 10 so far. Should also work with Android. If streaming from your device to the TV is what you need, than this is the way to go. It is much cheaper than AppleTV and also more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think currently there is a solution being developed for Apple devices. Basically, Apple develop their own protocol and only little information is available. It is quite different from the WiFi display standard (e.g., it does not use WiFi Direct/p2p at all and relies on mDNS) and I don't think lazycast will be of much use for Apple devices. At first glance, I do think that the hw of Raspberry Pi is perfectly capable of working as a receiver, but no one has implemented the protocol yet.